# I have a docker image of a springboot application with ENTRYPOINT["java"]. How I can execute a unit test within the application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have a springboot application which is deployed using docker. Its Dockerfile has ENTRYPOINT["java"], so I can execute the application with a java command, but I need to execute on demand the unit tests within the springboot application using docker. How I can do that?

I tried something like this

`docker run -it --rm --entrypoint mvn test-java-service test -Dtest=com.service.integration.ControllerTest`, but I get Junit dependecy is required.

Comment: is the jar a uber jar? Why not just build in the dependency into the image or include it in the jar?

Comment: In your pom change junit dependency to be included in jar, also junit test cases be included in jar

Comment: A typical Java image _only_ contains a JRE and the jar file built out of the main application code; the image wouldn't contain the source code or compiled unit tests at all, which means you can't run tests _after_ you've built the image.  Can you run the tests on your host system _before_ building the image?

Comment: (If your image doesn't look like that, please [edit] the question to include a [mcve].)

Comment: This is not good enough to understand the problem here, please share the code block along with what you've done.